# Wordpress loop - how to count items

Tags: wordpress, loops, count

Is there a way to get a number of items within Wordpress loop code:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

This loop lists the posts. <strike>I need to add certain classes to first 3 depending on the total number of them.</strike>

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use the [`post_count` property](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties) of `$WP_Query`, like so:

```
$wp_query->post_count
```

Be aware of the difference with `found_posts`, which counts the posts which, though matching the query, are not being displayed (e.g. for pagination). You might want to use one or the other depending on your particular situation.

Comment: Thank you both for answers. This one is closer to what I need. Perhaps I wasn't precise enough. I need number of items no matter how many of them is there. Then I need to add classes to first 3 or less if total<3 - but this shouldn't be the part of the question.

Comment: You can also use `$items = count($posts)` if you wish :)

Comment: Spot on! `found_posts ` was the one for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Here's one way to go about it:

```
<?php 
 $count = 0; //set up counter variable
 while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
 $count++; //increment the variable by 1 each time the loop executes
 if ($count<4) {
    // here put the special code for first three
 }
 // here put the code for normal posts
 endwhile;
 ?>
```

Comment: The OP needs the total number of posts in the loop, not the current index.

Comment: @Sunyatasattva "I need to add certain classes to first 3" - he needs to count and test if its less then 4 to add special classes to them... downvote? really?

Comment: Just after the quoted sentence *“depending on the total number of them.”* He doesn't just need to add the classes to the first three, these classes will depend on the total number. I downvoted because this doesn't answer the question. The downvote could always be taken back if you edit the answer to actually address the OP problem.

Comment: @Sunyatasattva you have a problem understanding loops and counters apparently, and I don't even read php. The OP is asking for the number of items as the loop is occurring. The current index indicates how many times the loop occurred, hence giving the count.

Comment: You can't figure out the total number of them in a while until the thing finishes executing; the OP must describe the total number in his post, which he didn't. Bojana's solution is fine based on what is asked.

Comment: @sksallaj I understand what a loop and what counters are, I believe you misread the OP question and based on your second comment you don't know about Wordpress. The OP will decide who misinterpreted. In any case: if you just wanted a counter, Wordpress `$WP_Query` has the convenient [`current_post` property](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties) which will give you the current loop index.

Answer (score 4):

I used this in mine

```
<?php $count = 0;
  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $count++;?>
        <div  class="col-lg-3">
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
        </div>

<?php if ($count==4) { $count = 0;?>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php } ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be `wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' )`

If you want to get it in a template and you don't have access to the loop variable, like in your example.

Comment: The OP asked about WordPress. `wc_get_loop_prop` is a function of WooCommerce and is not part of WordPress core.