# Different layout WordPress loop

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to achieve the following layout via WordPress loop:

### 1st post 2nd post

### 3rd post 4th post 5th post

### 6th post 7th post

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about flowing posts, you would probably assign classes or ids to the divs in the loop. Maybe using some sort of global variable from outside the loop to keep count, and then use css to change the width or float on the divs to make them flow like you wish.

First check if classes or divs you can use are already assigned.
Also take a look at how you can count nth elements with CSS.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

Comment: That would normally work but i can't get that set of elements in pairs, i need 2 elements that have col-6, 3 elements that have col-4 and then 2 elements that have col-6

Comment: I think either your post has to be more specific of what you are trying to achieve, or you need to link to a page where we can examine the source to see what you mean.
You could count inside the loop, and depending on the number, assign different classes to the divs.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303556/wordpress-loop-how-to-count-items/19303702

Comment: I've tried with 2 separated counts, one for post (number) and second one for rows, since every second row has different layout, first row is (6x6), second one is (4x4x4) but that didnt work too